# DependencyProperty Default Value

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties, default-value

I'm trying to get a DependencyProperty working in WPF. I'm using:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMode", typeof (TescoFoodSummary), typeof (Orientation), new UIPropertyMetadata(Orientation.Vertical));
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the orientation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The orientation.</value>
    public Orientation DisplayMode {
        get { return (Orientation)base.GetValue(DisplayModeProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(DisplayModeProperty, value); }
    }
```

When I initialize the window, I get an error: Default value type does not match type of property 'DisplayMode'. Howevere, if I leave the default value out I get a null reference exception when the window loads due to DisplayModeProperty not being set.

Comment: The second parameter is the property type, the third parameter is the type of the control, be attentive, swap them in your example.

Comment: Well that was a stupid mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @vorrtex: Please post that as an answer...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Posting comment as an answer.

According to msdn [DependencyProperty.Register Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502.aspx) the syntax looks so:

```
public static DependencyProperty Register(
    string name,
    Type propertyType,
    Type ownerType,
    PropertyMetadata typeMetadata
)
```

In your case ownerType is `TescoFoodSummary` and propertyType is `Orientation`, so parameters have the following positions:

```
DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMode", typeof (Orientation), typeof (TescoFoodSummary), new UIPropertyMetadata(Orientation.Vertical));
```

Comment: Thanks, an easy mistake to make.